# How to create a new workspace in Asana?

Tags: java, asana

I can create tasks in Asana using the Asana API (JAVA).

```
    import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
    import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthScope;
    import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
    import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PutMethod;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String data = "{" +
                    "    \"data\": {" +
                    "        \"workspace\": 4210637464884," +
                    "        \"name\": \"Task 2 this is it\"," +
                    "        \"notes\": \"NOTES_ABOUT_TASK_GO_HERE\"," +
                    "        \"assignee\": \"ykhonskiy@gmail.com\"" +
                    "   }," +
                    "    \"options\": {" +
                    "        \"fields\": \"name\"" +
                    "    }" +
                    "}";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);
            client.getParams().setParameter("http.useragent", "Test Client");
            client.getState().setCredentials(
                    new AuthScope("app.asana.com", 443, "realm"),
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("<APIKEY>", "")
            );

            BufferedReader br = null;
            PostMethod method = new PostMethod("https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks");
            method.setDoAuthentication(true);

            try {
                method.setRequestBody(data);
                int returnCode = client.executeMethod(method);
                System.out.println("Return code: " + returnCode);
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(method.getResponseBodyAsStream()));
                String readLine;
                while (((readLine = br.readLine()) != null)) {
                    System.out.println(readLine);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                method.releaseConnection();
                if (br != null) try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (Exception fe) {
                    System.err.println(fe);
                }
            }
            createNewWorkSpace();

        }
    }
```

It works fine. 
Now I want to create a workspace. How?
I tried to use

```
PutMethod method = new PutMethod("https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces");
String data = "{" +
            "  \"data\": {" +
            "    \"id\": 1234," +
            "    \"name\": \"Everyone's Favorite Workspace\"" +
            "  }}";
```

And I get 
Return code: 404
{"errors":[{"message":"No matching route for request"}]}

Please, help me!

Answer (score 0):

The Asana API does not support the creation of new workspaces.
At the moment it only supports the updating of a "specific, existing workspace", and even this this is limited to updating the name of the workspace.

As per Asana API documentation: https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/workspaces

PS I edited your API key from the post just in case it was in fact your real API key!